# QED at end of Theorem (definition-style) Environment

Tags: theorems, amsthm

Apologize if this is a duplicate.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\qed}%
%example
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
For example, if $E$ is the set of even numbers,
\begin{equation*}
\{x \in E: x = 2\}
\end{equation*}
is the set of all even numbers $x$ such that $x = 2$. Of course, there is only one even number equal to $2$, so 
\begin{equation*}
\{x \in E: x = 2\} = \{2\}\text{.}
\end{equation*}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can I somehow move `\qed` up one line, to the right of the `equation` environment by changing the `example` environment definition?

Comment: Why no use `\qedhere` inside `equation`. (`\{x \in E: x = 2\} = \{2\}\text{.}\qedhere`)?

Comment: @skpblack: that doesn’t work in this situation.  It works inside a `proof` environment, but not inside a `theorem`-style environment: a `\qedhere` on its own produces nothing, and a `\qed` inside the `equation` comes out immediately following the equation text, not right-aligned as one wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `ntheorem` package, you have an `automatic` placement of \qedsymbol, and it's easy to have several types of `\qedsymbol`s if you use the `thmmarks` option. The `amsthm` option provides a partial compatibility with the layouts defined in amsthm, but the syntax to define new theorem-like environments is more intuitive. Finally, the `thref` option provides extended refencing possibilities (compatible with cleveref).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
For example, if $E$ is the set of even numbers,
\begin{equation*}
\{x ∈ E: x = 2\}
\end{equation*}
is the set of all even numbers $x$ such that $x = 2$. Of course, there is only one even number equal to $2$, so
\begin{equation*}
\{x ∈ E: x = 2\} = \{2\}\text{.}
\end{equation*}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is rather bad style to end an example with a displayed material. If you cannot reformulate it, there is an exemplary solution. If you want the square to be moved to the right, you can replace `\qed` by `\tag*{\qed}`, but certainly only for unnumbered equations.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\qed}%
\newtheorem{exampleqed}[example]{Example}
\AtEndEnvironment{exampleqed}{}%
%example
\begin{document}

\begin{example}
For example, if $E$ is the set of even numbers,
\begin{equation*}
\{x \in E: x = 2\}
\end{equation*}
is the set of all even numbers $x$ such that $x = 2$. Of course, there is only one even number equal to $2$, so 
\begin{equation*}
\{x \in E: x = 2\} = \{2\}\text{.}
\end{equation*}
\end{example}

\begin{exampleqed}
For example, if $E$ is the set of even numbers,
\begin{equation*}
\{x \in E: x = 2\}
\end{equation*}
is the set of all even numbers $x$ such that $x = 2$. Of course, there is only one even number equal to $2$, so 
\begin{equation*}
\{x \in E: x = 2\} = \{2\}\text{.}
\qed
\end{equation*}
\end{exampleqed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This certainly works for my needs. Just simple and quick.  If worked just fine for an equation at the end of a section in which I prove a theorem using the IEEEtran template. Thanks!